# Using a chart as progress bar via a Userform

Tags: excel, charts, progress-bar, userform, self-updating

So I'm writing a macro that will have a few minutes of runtime. To let the user know that progress is being made and their excel isn't frozen, I want to show a progress bar. I am aware of how a classic progress bar works, however I tried making a doughnut-chart and using this as a progress bar (as it can get updated easily with the macro). However, I cannot get the chart to update once the userform shows.
Does anyone know of a way to have a chart as a progress bar and regularly update the userform? Can I even use a chart as a progress bar or do I have to go back to the classic progress bar?
I hope the question makes sense.
KR,
Quirky

Comment: welcome! please share your code and where you're stuck. see the [tour] (earn your 1st badge!) ans also see [ask] and how to create a [mcve]

Comment: also, check google... maybe this helps? https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/live-chart-in-a-userform.464438/